# How to show sensor output using Dino and Sinatra?

Tags: javascript, ruby, asynchronous, sinatra, arduino

I would like to show on my page output from one of my sensor(moisture) connected to Arduino.

Following script, gives me some value(number) every one second.

```
require 'dino'

board = Dino::Board.new(Dino::TxRx.new)
sensor = Dino::Components::Sensor.new(pin: 'A0', board: board)

on_data = Proc.new do |data|
  puts data
  sleep 1
end

sensor.when_data_received(on_data)

sleep
```

I think I can use `Sinatra` as API and `Javascript` script for showing asynchronously output.

So this should be something like that

```
%w(sinatra dino haml).each do |lib|
  require lib
end

board = Dino::Board.new(Dino::TxRx.new)
sensor = Dino::Components::Sensor.new(pin: 'A0', board: board)
sleep 1

get '/' do
  haml :index
end

get '/moisture' do
  on_data = Proc.new do |data|
    { moisture_value: data }
    sleep 1
  end

  sensor.when_data_received(on_data)
end
```

Could you give me some hints or simple good pattern how should I handle with that?

I found sample sinatra app fo dino: https://github.com/austinbv/dino_cannon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to back the asynchronous data read with some kind of datastore: db, filestore or a memory store. It would be best to abstract your sensor reading code into a separate class and have well defined API to read that data back. I recommend putting MoistureSensor class into a separate file and require it in your server file. Also, I am limiting number of data points in memory store to 1000. Try Following:

```
%w(json sinatra dino haml).each do |lib|
  require lib
end

class MoistureSensor
  require 'dino'
  board = Dino::Board.new(Dino::TxRx.new)
  sensor = Dino::Components::Sensor.new(pin: 'A0', board: board)
  @@data = []
  on_data = Proc.new do |data|
    @@data.shift if @@data.length > 1000
    @@data << data
    sleep 1
  end
  sensor.when_data_received(on_data)

  def self.data
    @@data
  end

  def self.last_entry
    @@data.last
  end
end

get '/' do
  haml :index
end

get '/moisture.json' do
  content_type :json
  { moisture_value: MoistureSensor.last_entry }.to_json
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks really fine. One thing left Is how is the best way to stream that json on page. Should I just get by ajax every one second that json and render it?

Comment: Yes and no. Depends on your requirement. If you dont care about displaying all data points read by the device (assuming it reads couple per second), then you should go ahead with your plan and fetch last datapoint every second or so and update your page using ajax. If you want to display all the datapoints than you need to have timestamp with your datapoints and ajax query so you can keep track of your last fetch time and return all datapoints between last fetch and Time.now.

Comment: @regedarek I added fix for json content_type per your edit/review. Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: One thing missing for me here is good and simple way how to render and refresh each 1 sec that json using JS

Comment: You need to handle that on client side javascript. Make a function that will call ajax (using jquery is easiest) every 1 second and refresh data on your page. you can use setTimeout javascript function to have it autocall every so often.